# Wrong IndexPath of my UICollectionView

Tags: ios, swift, indexing, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I have a problem on my UICollectionView.

I create my collectionView with 2 lists. 
The 2 lists contain a header for each ones.
For example when I click on the first cell on my first list, my code send me **indexPath.item = 0**. All is normal.
But when I click on the first index on my second list, my index also returns 0 ,but I prefer it following of the first list.

For example if I have 10 items in my first list **(indexPath 0 -> 9)** I would like the first object of my 2nd list is equal **to 10** and not start from beginning ! Thank you in advance.

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    if let cell = sender as? UICollectionViewCell,
      indexPath = collectionView?.indexPathForCell(cell),
      managePageViewController = segue.destinationViewController as? ManagePageViewController {
      managePageViewController.videoList = dataSource.pictureOfVideo
      managePageViewController.currentIndex = indexPath.item
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: `NSUInteger index = 0;for (NSUInteger i = 0; i < targetIndexPath.section; i ++){index += [yourCollectionView numberOfItemsInSection:i];} managePageViewController.currentIndex = index;` could do the trick.

Comment: If the two lists are part of separate sections, you can calculate the index based on `indexPath.section` along with `indexPath.row`

Comment: On my previous comment, forgot to add the current index: `index += indexPath.row`

Comment: an `indexPath` has a `section` and a `row` (for table views) or `item` (for collection views) value, those two indices together are your index path, which clearly identifies the each element in the current collection clearly.

Comment: Thank you, you'r answer help a lot ! I resolved my problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`IndexPath` for a cell provides you information on where it is located in the `collectionView`. The cell index can be identified by its `section` and `item` properties in `NSIndexPath`. Use the combination of these properties to identify the exact location.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `tags` in each list and check it when need to get the value, for example

```
if (list.tag == 0 && indexPath.item = 0){
   //list 1 and indexPath.item is 0
} 

if (list.tag == 1 && indexPath.item = 0){
   //list 2 and indexPath.item is 10
}
```

I don't know is there is a way to get direct this value because you are crate a new set of `CollcetionViewCell`. You can track based on the sections as well.